# Query a nested array in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, subquery

I would like to retrieve documents by the presence of an string in a nested array.  For example, the data (representing a dependency parse of a sentence) looks like:

```
{'tuples': [['xcomp', 'multiply', 'using'], 
            ['det', 'method', 'the'], 
            ['nn', 'method', 'foil'], 
            ['dobj', 'using', 'method']]}
```

The closest solution I've found assumes that `['nn', ...]` is the second position of the `tuples` list-of-lists:

```
 db.c.find({'tuples.2.0' : 'nn'})
```

Is there a way to relax the fixed position?   The tuples (not their contents) can be in any order.

Secondly, it would be really great to be able to retrieve documents that have  `['nn', 'method', X]`, meaning a noun "method" in their dependency parse.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Got it!

```
db.c.find({'tuples' : {$elemMatch : {$all : ['nn']}}})
db.c.find({'tuples' : {$elemMatch : {$all : ['nn','method']}}})
```

Comment: Even if you knew that 'nn' was in the third row, but didn't know in what position, you still need the $all. According to documentation for find, you shouldn't. Try this in mongo shell: db.nested.insert({'level1': {'level2': [['item00', 'item01'], ['item10', 'item11']]}}). Then,  db.nested.findOne({'level1.level2.0': 'item00'}) Why?